# Handle net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH error in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a JavaScript video playlist. The videos are served from another domain, not mine. And recently I discovered problems with playing some videos. Sometimes, I receive `net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH` error. These videos start playing and after 2-3 seconds they stop by themselves. Then they begin playing after 1-4 minutes. Only some videos have this behavior. 
Can I check somehow for this error before playing a video? I want to skip the video if the error is detected and play a next one.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this exact issue when I was trying to continually re-download an image that was continually being re-uploaded.

Unsurprisingly the image was sometimes incomplete but, even so, I've not found a way to prevent the error from being logged - but I can catch it like this:

```
    $('#myPic').attr('src', 'cacheless-pic.bmp?d='+ new Date().getTime())
       .on('error', function() {
          console.log('Oops - image of broken.');
       });
```

I'm uncertain if this will help with your videos, but it's all I've got right now!